# Insertion stored procedure does not recieve parameters

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created a stored procedure in my database to add data to a table but when I execute it from the Java aplication or from the panel of MySQL Workbench it never receives the parameters and it fills the table with empty fields.

This is the procedure:

```
create procedure insertSchool(in idSch int, name nvarchar(50), phone nvarchar(50))
insert into school values(idSch,name,phone);
```

When I execute the procedure through MySQL Workbench this code appears:

```
set @name = '0';
set @phone = '0';
call perezsuncin.insertarFacultad(8, @name, @phone);
select @name, @phone;
```

It is not a problem of the code that sends the parameters, it just fills the parameters with `0` instead.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertarFacultad`(in idFac int, nombre nvarchar(50), telefono nvarchar(50))
insert into facultad values(idFac,nombre,telefono)
```

this is all the code i have on the database, other tha this i cannot think of anything else i can post

i am not well versed in sql to be honest

Comment: Can you include the code which is calling your stored proc?

Comment: i just added a bit of an explication, and the code that apears when i execute the procedure through MySQL Workbench interface, but when i execute it directly throug hardcode it works just fine

Comment: Then I think we need to see the code of your actual stored procedure.

Comment: I'm guessing that your parameter names are the same as your column names - if so change them.